# How to get screen size and respond to it?

Tags: android

I am building a application for android honeycomb and regular phones.I want to be able to test if the screen is a certain size and respond to it a certain way. How would i go about getting the screen size in code?

Answer (score 2):

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= mDisplay.getWidth();
int Height= mDisplay.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

[getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindowManager%28%29)

You might also want to read this: http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html