# Android Different screen

Tags: java, android, screen-size

Welcome.

I need to prepare UI for different screen sizes. I make layouts
layout-small
layout-normal
layout-large
layout-XLARGE
For this I-small drawable, drawable-normal, drawable-large, drawable-XLARGE.
But where to get the screen size from small to XLARGE. I mean the size of
For example, 320 x 480 Where to get the dimensions for each screen? To prepare the graphics?

Comment: Hello, you should go through this [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Take a look at those links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577430/how-to-get-screen-size-and-respond-to-it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589101/how-to-get-screen-size-of-device

Comment: your question is unclear.Do want to test ur app on different screens?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do in code you can use Display class of android and use method getRectSize and getSize for the same. [Please See API here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29)

If you want to see the differences between screen sizes you can look at this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

But this is a different screen resolution, not size. I have no idea what size buttons to prepare (ImageButton) for each layout. MDPI / Hdpi not responsible for the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) at least. As bit of advice, you can start with the graphics for the mdpi device. For the mdpi devices 1 pixel is equivalent to 1 dpi. Then you can make the same graphic for the hdpi just multiply the pixel of the mdpi image * 1.5, and for the ldpi  just multiply the pixel of the mdpi image * 0.75..

Comment: 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

But this is a different screen resolution, not size. I have no idea what size buttons to prepare (ImageButton) for each layout. MDPI / Hdpi not responsible for the screen size.