# Can I get the size of the screen android phone?

Tags: java, android, screen-resolution, screen-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get screen size and respond to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577430/how-to-get-screen-size-and-respond-to-it)

Can I get the size of the screen android phone, similar to the same method in the computer. I'm interested in the screen resolution and (or) diagonal screen.
Is there a possibility to find me interesting information, it can be anologii transaction for Computer:

```
Toolkit toolkit = getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
int widthScreen = screenSize.width;
int heightScreen = screenSize.height;
```

Comment: please search before posting questions. this has been asked already

Comment: Sorry, but my English is not very good - I was looking for jobs with the promptness of words "get" "screen" "size" "android", вut not find the correct questions on the topic of interest to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

You can use it as follows:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

for density, there's

```
int densitiy = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
```

Comment: Never just post a link, always include the essential parts in your answer...

Comment: The Reference of DisplayMetrics is pretty selfexplaining and exactly, what he wants to know. Usually you're right though.

Comment: That is correct. However, when this website is down or no longer available, your answer will be useless.

Comment: when said website is down, any android developer should be able to recognize it is a link to the android javadoc, hence available localy if you have the sdk, hence one can trivially find it back. Also, when developer.android.com is no longer available, i doubt the relevance of this question.

Comment: That's true in this special case. But I should adopt the process anyway. Outside that it is more convenient for the op to have it at a glance and the link for further research. But let's not brake out in flames over this :)

Comment: @Fildor, sorry - but I can't  vote up your answer because I need 15  reputation.

Comment: Nevermind. Accepting it gives me reputation, too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following code to get the screen height and width.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
densityX = display.getWidth(); // default height width of screen
densityY = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: Please tick it as correct!!!:)

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int screen_width = display.getWidth();
int screen_height = display.getHeight();
```